# Powershell - Copy files and rename if same name found

Tags: powershell

I am a bit confused on how to achieve this. Any input would be great.

I have a source dir and a target directory. During copy, if the file exists with same last modified stamp, then don't bother doing anything to save CPU resources.
If the source dir has a file that exists in target but the source version has a newer modified date, then the existing file in target directory should be renamed to file_yyyymmddhhmmss (the old modified date)
This way the new file can get in.

I got the basic copy here but struggling how can i  amend this?

```
#Set source directory
$sourcedir="D:\Temp\2023\Source"
#Set target directory
$destinationdir="D:\Temp\2023\Destination"
#Set logfile - Add YYMMDDHHMMSS to log
$logfile="D:\Temp\2023\Log.txt"

robocopy $sourcedir $destinationdir /e /xo /log:$Logfile
```

If you think this can be achieved in Batch script, then fine. Otherwise Powershell is first preference.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly share the sample of the file names. is it just `log.txt` ?

Comment: Log file is fine. Wil ldo in YYMMDD format.

Issue is on the source  & target dirs. They can be around 20-30 gbs of data. There will be subfolders.